# CentOS kernel boot options prefixes: rd vs inst

Tags: linux-kernel, centos7, redhat, boot

I have the following boot options (for PXE purposes):

```
linuxefi /kernel/vmlinuz 
rd.debug
root=live:ftp://10.0.0.1/pub
inst.stage2=ftp://10.0.0.1/pub
ks=ftp://10.0.0.1/pub/kickstart.cfg
inst.ks=ftp://10.0.0.1/pub/kickstart.cfg
```

Obviously, some of them redundant. Other don't work. Dracut is part of Anaconda installer. So it's weird that Anaconda has own args that overwrite own dracut behaviour. 
In my situation kernel totally ignores inst* prefixes (CentOS 7.5).

**Question**:
What is the difference between [rd* prefix (rd.) and non-prefixed (root, ks)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/dracut.cmdline.7.html) vs. [inst* prefix](https://anaconda-installer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boot-options.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question. 
I was inattentive.
The answer is written in the [Anaconda doc](https://anaconda-installer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boot-options.html):

> Anaconda bootup is handled by dracut, so most of the kernel arguments handled by dracut are also valid. See dracut.kernel(7) for details on those options.
>   Throughout this guide, installer-specific options are prefixed with inst (e.g. inst.ks). Options specified without the inst prefix are recognized, but the prefix may be required in a future release.